# MYSQL 5.7 Note Got an error reading communication packets

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

134359 [Note] Got an error reading communication packets

Appears in logs every 5 minutes, I have seen a few similar posts on here however none actually match the error I'm seeing here.

MySQL 5.7 - configuration:

```
[mysqld]
##skip-name-resolve=1
#bind-address=localhost
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
innodb_file_per_table=1
performance-schema=1
server-id=2
auto_increment_offset = 2
auto_increment_increment= 5
report-host=2

log-slave-updates
##
replicate-ignore-db=mysql
replicate-ignore-db=cphulkd
replicate-ignore-db=information_schema
replicate-ignore-db=performance_schema
replicate-ignore-db=sys
##


max_connections=1000
table_open_cache=2000
wait_timeout=86400
interactive_timeout=86400
net_read_timeout=28800
net_write_timeout=28800
table_definition_cache=2000
thread_cache_size=100
long_query_time=10000
log_queries_not_using_indexes=0
innodb_page_cleaners=128
sql_mode=""
max_allowed_packet=512M
local-infile=0

[mysql]
# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 10M
##myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 10000M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 0

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 100M
max-heap-table-size            = 100M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
#max-connections               = 1000
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 1024
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 2024

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 10G
innodb_log_buffer_size         = 5G
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 80G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances   = 64
innodb_write_io_threads        = 64
innodb_read_io_threads         = 64
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct     = 90
innodb_io_capacity             = 1000
innodb_stats_on_metadata       = 0
innodb_adaptive_flushing       = 1
innodb_lru_scan_depth          = 1024

# LOGGING #
log-error                       = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes   = 0
slow-query-log                 = 0
slow-query-log-file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
join_buffer_size                = 55M
binlog_cache_size               = 16M
key_buffer_size                 = 50M
```

The thread ID 134359 doesn't correspond to any actual threads if I enable General MySQL Logging, nor does anything appear in a tcpdump during the events occuring.

At a loss? I do feel it's something CPanel or WHM related

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server and Number of Cores 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: When will you post your RAM size and other requested information?

Comment: Is there a reason you have two [mysqld] sections in your configuration?

Comment: Will be able to help you after additional information requested is posted.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?